# Problems using pip to install libraries from github for python3.4 on an ubuntu 14.04 machine

Tags: python, ubuntu, github, pip, chromebook

Firstly I'm a first year computer science major so inexpeirence maybe my problem here but I can't find a solid solution after about 4 hours of googling and stumbling about.

I'm trying to install a library from github to use in python3.4 to play around with and learn about using api's.  I'm using a Chromebook (Asus C300m) with ubuntu dual booted for coding.

I've tried various methods of using pip to install the library.  It seems using the default pip command is broken for my version of ubuntu and throws an "incomplete read" error.

I tried using the get-pip.py file instead and that seems to work. But that installs the library only to the 2.7 version of python that came with the OS install not the 3.4 version I have to use for class and am currently learning in.

I also tried installing and using pip3 but that throws an "incomplete read" error just like the default pip command did.

I'm very willing to link my failed console commands but there have been so many I'm not sure which would be most helpful.

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: Just run the `get-pip.py` script with `python3` instead of `python` and it should install the latest `pip` for your 3.4.

Comment: But first, have you tried `apt-get` to update your Python 3.4? Because if its built-in `pip` is broken, who knows what else may be broken?

Comment: Jeez man I thought I tried every combination of python and the number three that I could think of but I guess I missed that one.  That helped me get the api I was looking for.  Thank you so much.